# Cleaner way to set full widths for sections in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <h3>Title of Text</h3>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <hr />
          </Col>
          <Col xs={12}> The content goes here</Col>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <hr />
          </Col>
        </Row>
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I want each to go on a separate line but it looks like I would have to set the col width to 12 to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply separate it by `row`. Like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h3>Title of Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        The content goes here
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
```

Or else use `col-12` as you've mentioned.

PS: `col` in this context is used only to remove the negative lateral margins from `row`. If you remove its negative margins, you can even discard `col` entirely, to get even cleaner.